Clarification on the degree of the extension of fields
Suppose $f$ is the unique minimal polynomial which $b$ satisfies, for some $b \notin K$, $K$ being a field. I then extend $K$ by adjoining $b$, i.e. taking $L = K(b)$. I have some questions which I cannot wrap my head around:

$L$ need not be a splitting field, right? For instance, taking $x^3 - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not a splitting field of this polynomial.
The degree of the extension by adjoining $b$ is $\deg f$, as it can be seen as taking the quotient modulo $f$. However, this is only true if you only adjoin one root, correct? Meaning, for instance that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$, for $\zeta$ a 3rd root fo unity, but if I were to adjoin both, then the degree of the extension changes due to the tower law.

This comes because the example $K(\sqrt{\sqrt{b}})$ has degree 4 over $K$ (assuming $b$ not a square etc.) and $K(\sqrt{-\sqrt{b}})$ has degree 4 as well. They both satisfy the minimal polynomial $x^4 - b$, and it checks out. However, I need clarification on why, if their minimal polynomial is the same, then $K(\sqrt{\sqrt{b}}, \sqrt{-\sqrt{b}})$ doesn't have degree 4 (it could have degree 8, following from the tower law), if we are just taking the quotient modulo the same minimal polynomial. Maybe we're taking the quotient twice?
Thanks!

It doesn't have degree $4$ for the same reason that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ does not have degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, even though $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$ are both roots of $x^3-2$.
After you adjoint $\sqrt{b}$, the polynomial $x^4-b$ now splits into two quadratics, $(x^2-\sqrt{b})(x^2+\sqrt{b})$ in $K(\sqrt{b})[x]$. $\sqrt{\sqrt{b}}$ is a root of the first quadratic, $\sqrt{-\sqrt{b}}$ is a root of the second quadratic. If the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$, then these are distinct irreducible polynomials.
Yes, $K(\sqrt{\sqrt{b}})$ is isomorphic to $K(\sqrt{-\sqrt{b}})$ over $K$, but they are not equal. Just like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ are isomorphic but not equal. So adding both roots will give you an extension of degree greater than $4$.
In $K(\sqrt{\sqrt{b}})$, the polynomial $x^4-b$ factors as
$$x^4-b = (x-\sqrt{\sqrt{b}})(x+\sqrt{\sqrt{b}})(x^2+\sqrt{b})$$
with $x^2+\sqrt{b}$ irreducible. In $K(\sqrt{-\sqrt{b}})$ the polynomial factors as
$$x^4-b = (x-\sqrt{-\sqrt{b}})(x+\sqrt{-\sqrt{b}})(x^2-\sqrt{b}),$$
with $x^2-\sqrt{b}$ irreducible.

Your comment is very illustrative. So, is then $K$ adjoining both roots just the quotient of $K$ by a polynomial of degree 8?

@Chuwee Yes... but that is the result of the Primitive Element Theorem, that tells you that every finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be obtained by adding a single element.

Thank you, Don Arturo
